# HashMap holding Vec buffer and slice to buffer

Tags: rust, slice, nom

I am trying to store into a `HashMap` the result of a parsing operation on a text file (parsed with [nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom)). The result is comprised of a `Vec` buffer and some slices over that buffer. The goal is to store those together in a tuple or struct as a value in the hash map (with `String` key). But I can't work around the lifetime issues.

#### Context

The parsing itself takes an `&[u8]` and returns some data structure containing slices over that same input, *e.g.*:

```rust
struct Cmd<'a> {
  pub name: &'a str
}

fn parse<'a>(input: &'a [u8]) -> Vec<Cmd<'a>> {
  [...]
}
```

Now, because the parsing operates on slices without storage, I need to first store the input text in a `Vec` so that the output slices remain valid, so something like:

```rust
struct Entry<'a> {
  pub input_data: Vec<u8>,
  pub parsed_result: Vec<Cmd<'a>>
}
```

Then I would ideally store this `Entry` into a `HashMap`. This is were troubles arise. I tried two different approaches:

#### Attempt A: Store then parse

Create the `HashMap` entry first with the input, parse referencing the `HashMap` entry directly, and then update it.

```rust
pub fn store_and_parse(filename: &str, map: &mut HashMap<String, Entry>) {
  let buffer: Vec<u8> = load_from_file(filename);
  let mut entry = Entry{ input_data: buffer, parsed_result: vec![] };
  let cmds = parse(&entry.input_data[..]);
  entry.parsed_result = cmds;
  map.insert(filename.to_string(), entry);
}
```

This doesn't work because the borrow checker complains that `&entry.input_data[..]` borrows with the same lifetime as `entry`, and therefore cannot be moved into `map` as there's an active borrow.

```
error[E0597]: `entry.input_data` does not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:26:23
   |
23 | pub fn store_and_parse(filename: &str, map: &mut HashMap<String, Entry>) {
   |                                        --- has type `&mut std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, Entry<'1>>`
...
26 |     let cmds = parse(&entry.input_data[..]);
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
27 |     entry.parsed_result = cmds;
28 |     map.insert(filename.to_string(), entry);
   |     --------------------------------------- argument requires that `entry.input_data` is borrowed for `'1`
29 | }
   | - `entry.input_data` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `entry` because it is borrowed
  --> src\main.rs:28:38
   |
26 |     let cmds = parse(&entry.input_data[..]);
   |                       ---------------- borrow of `entry.input_data` occurs here
27 |     entry.parsed_result = cmds;
28 |     map.insert(filename.to_string(), entry);
   |         ------                       ^^^^^ move out of `entry` occurs here
   |         |
   |         borrow later used by call
```

#### Attempt B: Parse then store

Parse first, then try to store both the `Vec` buffer and the data slices into it all together into the `HashMap`.

```rust
pub fn parse_and_store(filename: &str, map: &mut HashMap<String, Entry>) {
  let buffer: Vec<u8> = load_from_file(filename);
  let cmds = parse(&buffer[..]);
  let entry = Entry{ input_data: buffer, parsed_result: cmds };
  map.insert(filename.to_string(), entry);
}
```

This doesn't work because the borrow checker complains that `cmds` has same lifetime as `&buffer[..]` but `buffer` will be dropped by the end of the function. It ignores the fact that `cmds` and `buffer` have the same lifetime, and are both (I wish) moved into `entry`, which is itself moved into `map`, so there should be no lifetime issue here.

```
error[E0597]: `buffer` does not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:33:21
   |
31 | pub fn parse_and_store(filename: &str, map: &mut HashMap<String, Entry>) {
   |                                        --- has type `&mut std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, Entry<'1>>`
32 |   let buffer: Vec<u8> = load_from_file(filename);
33 |   let cmds = parse(&buffer[..]);
   |                     ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
34 |   let entry = Entry{ input_data: buffer, parsed_result: cmds };
35 |   map.insert(filename.to_string(), entry);
   |   --------------------------------------- argument requires that `buffer` is borrowed for `'1`
36 | }
   | - `buffer` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `buffer` because it is borrowed
  --> src\main.rs:34:34
   |
31 | pub fn parse_and_store(filename: &str, map: &mut HashMap<String, Entry>) {
   |                                        --- has type `&mut std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, Entry<'1>>`
32 |   let buffer: Vec<u8> = load_from_file(filename);
33 |   let cmds = parse(&buffer[..]);
   |                     ------ borrow of `buffer` occurs here
34 |   let entry = Entry{ input_data: buffer, parsed_result: cmds };
   |                                  ^^^^^^ move out of `buffer` occurs here
35 |   map.insert(filename.to_string(), entry);
   |   --------------------------------------- argument requires that `buffer` is borrowed for `'1`
```

#### Minimal (non-)working example

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Cmd<'a> {
    name: &'a str
}

fn parse<'a>(input: &'a [u8]) -> Vec<Cmd<'a>> {
    Vec::new()
}

fn load_from_file(filename: &str) -> Vec<u8> {
    Vec::new()
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Entry<'a> {
    pub input_data: Vec<u8>,
    pub parsed_result: Vec<Cmd<'a>>
}

// pub fn store_and_parse(filename: &str, map: &mut HashMap<String, Entry>) {
//     let buffer: Vec<u8> = load_from_file(filename);
//     let mut entry = Entry{ input_data: buffer, parsed_result: vec![] };
//     let cmds = parse(&entry.input_data[..]);
//     entry.parsed_result = cmds;
//     map.insert(filename.to_string(), entry);
// }

pub fn parse_and_store(filename: &str, map: &mut HashMap<String, Entry>) {
  let buffer: Vec<u8> = load_from_file(filename);
  let cmds = parse(&buffer[..]);
  let entry = Entry{ input_data: buffer, parsed_result: cmds };
  map.insert(filename.to_string(), entry);
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

#### Edit: Attempt with 2 maps

As Kevin pointed, and this is what threw me off the first time (above attempts), the borrow checker doesn't understand that moving a `Vec` doesn't invalidate the slices because the heap buffer of the `Vec` is not touched. Fair enough.

*Side note: I am ignoring the parts of Kevin's answer related to using indexes (the Rust documentation [explicitly states slices are a better replacement for indices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html), so I feel this is working against the language) and the use of external crates (which also are explicitly working against the language). I am trying to learn and understand how to do this "the Rust way", not at all costs.*

So my immediate reaction to that was to change the data structure: first insert the storage `Vec` into a first `HashMap`, and once it's there call the `parse()` function to create the slices directly pointing into the `HashMap` value. Then store those into a second `HashMap`, which would naturally dissociate the two. However that also doesn't work as soon as I put all of that in a loop, which is the broader goal of this code:

```rust
fn two_maps<'a>(
    filename: &str,
    input_map: &'a mut HashMap<String, Vec<u8>>,
    cmds_map: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<Cmd<'a>>>,
    queue: &mut Vec<String>) {
    {
        let buffer: Vec<u8> = load_from_file(filename);
        input_map.insert(filename.to_string(), buffer);
    }
    {
        let buffer = input_map.get(filename).unwrap();
        let cmds = parse(&buffer[..]);
        for cmd in &cmds {
            // [...] Find further dependencies to load and parse
            queue.push("...".to_string());
        }
        cmds_map.insert(filename.to_string(), cmds);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut input_map = HashMap::new();
    let mut cmds_map = HashMap::new();
    let mut queue = Vec::new();
    queue.push("file1.txt".to_string());
    while let Some(path) = queue.pop() {
        println!("Loading file: {}", path);
        two_maps(&path[..], &mut input_map, &mut cmds_map, &mut queue);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that once the input buffer is in the first map `input_map`, referencing it binds the lifetime of each new parsed result to the entry of that `HashMap`, and therefore the `&'a mut` reference (the `'a` lifetime added). Without this, the compiler complains that data flows from `input_map` into `cmds_map` with unrelated lifetimes, which is fair enough. But with this, the `&'a mut` reference to `input_map` becomes locked on the first loop iteration and never released, and the borrow checker chokes on the second iteration, quite rightfully so.

So I am stuck again. Is what I am trying to do completely unreasonable and impossible in Rust? How can I approach the problem (algorithms, data structures) to make things work lifetime-wise? I really don't see what's the "Rust way" here to store a collection of buffers and slices over those buffers. Is the only solution (that I want to avoid) to first load all files, and then parse them? This is *very* impractical in my case because most files contain references to other files, and I want to load the minimum chain of dependencies (likely < 10 files), not the entire collection (which is something like 3000+ files), and I can only access dependencies by parsing each file.

It seems the core of the issue is that storing the input buffers into any kind of data structure requires a mutable reference to said data structure for the duration of the insert operation, which is incompatible with having long-lived immutable references to each single buffer (for the slices) because those references need to have the same lifetime as per the `HashMap` definition. Is there any other data structure (maybe immutable ones) that lifts this? Or am I completely on the wrong track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, because the parsing operates on slices without storage, I need to first store the input text in a Vec so that the output slices remain valid, so something like:
>
> ```rust
> struct Entry<'a> {
>   pub input_data: Vec<u8>,
>   pub parsed_result: Vec<Cmd<'a>>
> }
> ```

What you are attempting here is a **“self-referential structure”**, where `parsed_result` refers to `input_data`. There is an incidental and a fundamental reason why this cannot work as written.

The incidental reason is that this struct declaration contains the lifetime *parameter* `'a`, but actually the lifetime you're attempting to give `parsed_result` is the lifetime of the struct itself, and there is no Rust syntax to specify that lifetime.

The fundamental reason is that Rust allows structs (and other values) to be **moved** to other locations in memory, and **references are just statically checked pointers**. So, when you write

```
map.insert(filename.to_string(), entry);
```

you're causing the value of `entry` to be *moved* from the stack frame to the HashMap's storage. That move invalidates any references into `entry`, whether or not `entry` contains those references itself. That's what the error "cannot move out of `entry` because it is borrowed" means; the borrow checker is not allowing the move to happen.

In your Attempt B,

```
  let buffer: Vec<u8> = load_from_file(filename);
  let cmds = parse(&buffer[..]);
  let entry = Entry{ input_data: buffer, parsed_result: cmds };
```

the problem is that you're moving `buffer` (into the `Entry`) while `cmds` borrows it. Again, that means the references (just fancy pointers!) into `buffer` would become invalid, so it's not allowed.

(Now, since `Vec` stores its actual data in a heap-allocated vector that will stay put while the `Vec` is moved, this might actually be safe, but the Rust borrow checker doesn't care about that.)

### Solutions

The simplest solution (from a language perspective) is to have each `Cmd` store indices into `input_data` instead of references. Indices don't become invalid when the object is moved since they're relative. The disadvantage of this is of course that you have to slice the input data every time — code has to carry around the `Entry` as well as the `Cmd`.

However, there *are* tools available to make self-referential structures, without even needing to write any unsafe code. The crates [ouroboros](https://docs.rs/ouroboros/) and [rental](https://docs.rs/rental/) both allow you to define self-referential structs, at the price of having to use special functions to access the struct fields.

For example, your code might look something like this using `ouroboros` (I haven't tested this):

```rust
use ouroboros::self_referencing;

#[self_referencing]
struct Entry {
    input_data: Vec<u8>,
    #[borrows(input_data)]
    parsed_result: Vec<Cmd<'this>> // 'this is a special lifetime name provided by ouroboros
}

fn parse_and_store(filename: &str, map: &mut HashMap<String, Entry>) {
    let entry = EntryBuilder {  // EntryBuilder is defined by ouroboros to help construct Entry
        input_data: load_from_file(filename),
        // Note that instead of giving a value for parsed_result, we give
        // a function to compute it.
        parsed_result_builder: |input_data: &[u8]| parse(input_data),
    }.build();
    map.insert(filename.to_string(), entry);
}

fn do_something_with_entry(entry: &Entry) {
    entry.with_parsed_result(|cmds| {
        // cmds is a reference to `self.parsed_result` which only lives as
        // long as this lambda and therefore can't be invalidated by a move.
    });
}
```

`ouroboros` (and `rental`) provide a fairly odd interface for accessing fields. If, like me, you don't want to expose that interface to your users (or the rest of your code), you can write a wrapper struct around the self-referential struct whose `impl` contains methods designed for how you want the structure to be used, so all of the odd field access methods can remain private.

Comment: Thanks @kevin-reid for the answer! That makes sense, I didn't consider the borrow checker might not understand the `Vec` move being safe. I edited my question, because I would like to learn how to do this "the Rust way" without working around the language, which I feel both the use of indices and the external crates for self-referencing structs are doing. I don't think what I am asking is completely unreasonable from a language perspective, but I still don't see how to approach this to make it work lifetime-wise.

Comment: @djee If there's a better way I don't know of it, and I would like to, so if you find something let me know. But I'll be surprised if there is. I also suspect that experienced Rust folks — I'm not one, really — would say that avoiding crates is missing the point; certainly they say it about trying to stick to the standard library only (since it is deliberately minimal).

Comment: I absolutely agree, I am not avoiding crates for the sake of it, I am avoiding those very specific ones which are working around the language because I want to learn how an expert would design that in a way the language expects it to be designed. Also, the reason I am convinced this is possible in some form is that those steps are actually what a compiler does with includes/imports. I looked at the `rustc` but didn't figure out yet how it handles that. One thing though: I need `Rc` since a file can be referenced from multiple other ones.

Comment: For reference some `rustc` details: [`SourceMap`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/388ef349043f20a1a8a3011eaf49dee220485e0a/compiler/rustc_span/src/source_map.rs#L167) and [`SourceFile`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f7801d6c7cc19ab22bdebcc8efa894a564c53469/compiler/rustc_span/src/lib.rs#L1106). But it uses byte offset ([`BytePos`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f7801d6c7cc19ab22bdebcc8efa894a564c53469/compiler/rustc_span/src/lib.rs#L1713)), not slices, and maybe that's the critical difference.